# Не могу скачать библиотеки. Не установлен? PIP

Tags: python, pip

Пытаюсь скачать библиотеки для питона. Уперся в то что не могу поставить pip. Он вроде и есть, а вроде и нет. Библиотеки разумеется никакие не скачиваются. Что надо исправить? Разбираюсь самостоятельно, прошу прощения за тривиальные вопросы

```
C:\Users\mkda6>py
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()

C:\Users\mkda6>py -m pip install -U pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\mkda6\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (21.3.1)

C:\Users\mkda6>pip
"pip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

C:\Users\mkda6>
```

Comment: может быть попробовать conda?

Comment: py -m pip install -U lib_name